# Deleting files from HDFS | Scala

Tags: scala, hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to **delete files that are more than two hours old**. To do this i am trying the following:

```
import java.util.Date
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

def cleaningHDFS(path: String) = {
    
    //Actual Date
    val fechaActual = new Date()
    //2h less
    var millisec_byDay = 1000 * 60 * 60
    var fechaActualMenosDos = new Date(fechaActual.getTime() - (millisec_byDay * 1))
    var fechaDef = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(fechaActualMenosDos)
    //Hasta aquí se obtiene la fecha actual menos dos días
    val conf = spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration;
    val fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
    val dirPath = new Path(path);
    val filestatus = fs.listFiles(dirPath);
    val df:SimpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    
    //Deleting files
    println(fechaDef)
    filestatus.foreach(f =>
      if(df.format(f.getModificationTime) < fechaDef) {
        println(df.format(f.getModificationTime))
        fs.delete(f,true);
      }
    );
```

But is not working for me, what am I doing wrong? I am having the error in the foreach because type mismacht

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Don't use `<` between formatted strings. Use actual Date functions for checking `isBefore` / `isAfter`

Comment: @OneCricketeer when I try to use it, tell me thats isBefore is not a member of a string. If i am using df as a SimpleDateFormat would be working, right?

Comment: Like I said, don't use formatted strings. `fechaActualMenosDos` is a Date object. So is `f.getModificationTime`. Compare those directly